# What is the MM/DD/YYYY regular expression and how do I use it in php?

Tags: php, regex, date

I found the regular expression for MM/DD/YYYY at http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/datemmddyyyy.html but I don't think I am using it correctly.

Here's my code:

```
$date_regex = '(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d';

$test_date = '03/22/2010';
if(preg_match($date_regex, $test_date)) {
  echo 'this date is formatted correctly';  
} else {
  echo 'this date is not formatted correctly';  
}
```

When I run this, it still echoes 'this date is not formatted correctly', when it should be saying the opposite. How do I set this regular expression up in php?

Comment: It also gives `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '['`

Comment: There's plenty of correct answers below, but one thing I haven't seen mentioned is that this pattern doesn't correctly extract the year... just the century. You'd need to change it to `/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20\d\d)/`.

Comment: @fiXedd: It doesn't look like he's trying to extract anything....

Comment: @BillYONeal, you're right, he isn't trying to capture anything in the example he gave. I was just pointing out that the pattern had captures that were wrong in case he (or someone else) intends to use it now that he got the example working.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The problem is one of delimeters and escaped characters (as others have mentioned). This will work:

```
$date_regex = '/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/';

$test_date = '03/22/2010';
if(preg_match($date_regex, $test_date)) {
  echo 'this date is formatted correctly';
} else {
  echo 'this date is not formatted correctly';
}
```

Note that I added a forward-slash to the beginning and ending of the expression and escapped (with a back-slash) the forward-slashes in the pattern.

To take it one step further, this pattern won't properly extract the year... just the century. You'd need to change it to `/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]((?:19|20)\d\d)/` and (as Jan pointed out below) if you want to make sure the whole string matches (instead of some subset) you'll want to go with something more like `/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]((?:19|20)\d\d)$/`.

---

As others have mentioned, [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) might be a better option if you're just trying to get the date out. It can parse almost any commonly used format and it will give you a unix timestamp. You can use it like this:

```
$test_date = '03/22/2010';

// get the unix timestamp for the date
$timestamp = strtorime($test_date);

// now you can get the date fields back out with one of the normal date/time functions. example:
$date_array = getdate($timestamp);
echo 'the month is: ' . $date_array['month'];
```

Comment: The "year" group doesn't work right after your change.  You need to isolate the alternation in its own group, preferably non-capturing: `((?:19|20)\d\d)`.

Comment: No, that's what you get for not testing it on dates in the years 1900 to 1999.  You also didn't test it on `1212/12/201010`.

Comment: Can someone explain this regex to me? I can barely understand it.

Answer (score 6):

Regex of the author of the question is almost correct. Date is not validated because a pattern should be:

```
  pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)\d\d$"
```

or if to be fancy:

```
  pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"
```

Please note that this pattern checks only for a format of a date and max/min values for individual date elements. That means a user's entry should be checked for validity of date in JavaScript function and/or a Server (e.g February 29 should not be allowed if a year is not a leap one).

As a side note, if you would like to allow a single digit (let's say for a month), change a month part to

```
([0-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])
```

Explanation:
 [0-9] - single digit between 0 and 9
 or
 0[1-9] - two digits between 01 and 09
 or
 1[012] - two digits limited to 10, 11, 12

Answer (score 5):

Its probably better to use strtotime() which will convert nearly any human-readable date format to a unix timestamp.  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: How will strtotime help me see if the user entered the string in the MM/DD/YYYY format? Can you give me an example? I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: strtotime can read the date in any format and you can verify to see if its returned value is valid.

Answer (score 5):

You need [correct delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) around the pattern.

```
$date_regex = '~(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d~';
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [checkdate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function as well. No need regex.

```
$str="03/22/2010";
list($mth,$day,$yr)=explode("/",$str);
var_dump(checkdate($mth,$day,$yr));
```

Comment: +1 for a simple, non-regex based solution.  However, the example may need a little work.  I believe it'd match the string `"03/22/2010/2011"` or `"03/22/2010///"`

Comment: @Frank Farmer: explode("/",$str, 3); maybe? That will limit explode to 3 elements, meaning 03/22/2010/2011 will come out as { 03 , 22 , 2010/2011 }, where the year part is now obviously invalid.

Answer (score 1):

To use this regex to validate dates in PHP code, you need to correctly format it as a string with additional regex delimiters as the PHP preg functions require.  You also need to add anchors to force the regex to match the entire string (or else fail to match):

```
$date_regex = '%\A(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d\z%'; 

$test_date = '03/22/2010'; 
if(preg_match($date_regex, $test_date)) { 
  echo 'this date is formatted correctly';   
} else { 
  echo 'this date is not formatted correctly';   
}
```

Of course, a library call would be better in this situation.  The regex allows invalid dates such as February 31st.

The regex can be useful if you want to scan a string for dates.  In that case you don't need the anchors.  You may still need an extra check to exclude invalid dates.  That depends on whether your input is know to contain only valid dates or not.

Answer (score 1):

This checks valid dates from `MM/DD/1960` to `MM/DD/2014`

Also accepts dates like `M/D/YYYY` and `0M/0D/YYYY`

```
^(?:[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:[0-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])/(?:20[6-9][0-9]|20[0-1][0-4])$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs delimiters:

`/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/`

Comment: It also needs the backslashes escaped -- the ones on the `\d`s. EDIT: And the escapes on the character classes need double escapes.

Comment: It also doesn't capture the year correctly, it'll only capture the 19 or 20... not 2010.

Comment: @Billy: the backslashes don't need to be escaped if the enclosing string literal uses single-quotes, e.g. `'/(19|20)\d\d/'`.  In fact, PHP is pretty forgiving about that even in double-quoted strings, but it's usually best to use single-quotes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

String timeStamp = "03/11/2018 17:51:45";

private static Pattern TIMESTAMP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/"
            + "([1-9][0-9]{3}) ([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])");

```
private static boolean isTimeStampValid(String timeStamp) {
        boolean isFeb = timeStamp.split("/")[0].matches("(0?[2])");
        if (isFeb) {
            boolean isValidFebDate = timeStamp.split("/")[1].matches("(0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-8])");
            if (!isValidFebDate) return false;
        }
        return TIMESTAMP_PATTERN.matcher(timeStamp).matches();
    }
```