# best date regex mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, regex, date, date-format

please help me to find the best regex for the dateformat `mm/dd/yyy` and `m/d/yyyy`.

i have tried different links but everyone has some problems. so please help me to solve this.

[What is the MM/DD/YYYY regular expression and how do I use it in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520633/what-is-the-mm-dd-yyyy-regular-expression-and-how-do-i-use-it-in-php)

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/datemmddyyyy.html

Comment: Why do you need a regex? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly have you tried and which issues had it?

Comment: @Oded   i want to validate date in the given formats

Comment: I can't comment on the regex (it would be quite complicated if possible), but I can tell you that normally people use the date format yyyyMMdd.  If dates are in this format, they can be treated as numbers when doing comparisons and can be numerically sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) overloads (or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) if you want more control) to validate whether a string is a valid representation of a `DateTime`.

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(someInputString, out dt)
{
  // it is valid and dt can be used
}
```

This would be a better approach than regular expressions - it is faster, well tested and will produce a valid `DateTime` object.

Comment: In conjunction with a custom validator?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regular expression then something like this would work (for most cases, since it allows 31st of February).

```
(0?\d|1[012])\/([012]?\d|3[01])\/\d{4}
```

Usually it is much better to use DateTime parsing for verifying date formats. Like `DateTime.TryParseExact` method. You can use the regular expression in the browser (in JavaScript) but you should really use DateTime parsing on the server side.

Comment: this seems like a better solution when there could be other text surrounding the date, which happens to be my situation.  Thanks.